# PHP iterative date modify = last day of month

Tags: php, date

I make a application that makes a lot of things, but what is important here, it takes a startingDate, and depending on frequency and duration, it modifies date by this amount of months.

For example :

```
$startingDate = new DateTime('2000-01-31');
$duration = 190;
$frequency = 12; //(monthly)
//So, if frequency is monthly, this date will iterative change 190 times by one month
```

If I have a starting date of 31th of January and I add 1 month, it return me a date of 2th of March.
I am trying to make a script that will add months to date in this way :

```
starting date : 31/01/2000
+1 month = 29/02/2000
+2 months = 31/03/2000
+3 months = 30/04/2000 
....
+13 months = 28/02/2001
```

Another case :

```
Starting date : 28/02/2001
+1 month : 31/03/2001
+2 months : 30/04/2001
...
```

So, the idea is.. if starting date is the last day of the current month, ending date must be the last day of month.

So, here is my code :

```
// $date came from object
for($i = 0; $i < $duration; $i++){
    //calculation stuff
    $this->array[$i] = array(
                              'Date' => $date->format('d/m/y'),
                              'Capital' => $capital,
                              'Rate' => $rate,
                              );
                  $capital = $remaining;
    //end of calculation stuff
                  $months = (12/$frequency). ' months';
                  $h = 12/$frequency;

      $currentDay = $date->format('d');
      if($currentDay == $date->format('t') ) {  
            if ( $h == 1) { 
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');  
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');  
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
                  } 
            if ( $h == 6) { 
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');  
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
                  }         
          if ( $h == 4) { 
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
              $date->modify('last day of next month');
                  } 


           if ( $h == 12) { 
              $date->modify('last day of next ');
                  } 

           } else {
            $date->modify($months);
           }
         }//for
```

With this code, when I put starting date of 31 January 2000 (last day in this month) it gives me next values in the right way :

```
29/02/00,
31/03/00,
... 
28/02/01 
...
```

When I put  starting date of 29/02/2000 and frequency = 2 (half-yearly) it gives me :

```
29/02/00,
31/08/00,
28/02/00,
31/08/01 // (right calculations)
```

And here is an error : 
When I put starting date of 28/02/2000 (not the last day in this month), it gives me :

```
28/02/00,
28/08/00,
28/02/01 //(last day in this month),
31/08/01,
28/02/02,
31/08/02,
... //Error here.
```

When I put a starting date of 30/04/2000 and frequency monthly(12) it gives me :

```
30/04/2000,
30/05/2000,
30/06/2000,
30/07/2000,
30/08/2000,
...
30/01/2001,
02/03/2001, 
02/04/2001, 
02/05,2001 
...
```

How can I fix this bugs and/or upgrade the code ?

Answer (score 0):

"t" returns the number of days in the month of a given date :

```
$a_date = "2017-07-23";
echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime($a_date));
```

Comment: I know that... I get in stuck cause if on this cycle initial date became last day of current month, after that is launched another if, that put wrong dates.